# Xamarin portable project navigate with ToolbarItem to another page by using MasterDetailPage

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am creating mini application and I want to make navigation from my toolbox label to another page.
My App.cs :

```
public class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            MainPage = new MainPage();
        }
        protected override void OnStart()
        {}
    }
```

This is my Main page which inherits from MasterDetailPage :

```
public partial class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        masterPage.ListView.ItemSelected += OnItemSelected;

        if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Windows)
        {
            Master.Icon = "swap.png";
        }

        CityClick.Clicked += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new Cities());
        };
    }
    void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = e.SelectedItem as MasterPageItem;
        if(item != null)
        {
            Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType));
            masterPage.ListView.SelectedItem = null;
            IsPresented = false;
        }
    }
```

And this is MainPage XAML structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DD.Learning;assembly=DD.Learning"
                  x:Class="DD.Learning.MainPage"
          MasterBehavior="Popover">
  <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem x:Name="CityClick"
                 Text="City :"
                 Order="Primary">
    </ToolbarItem>
  </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

  <MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <local:MasterPage x:Name="masterPage" />
  </MasterDetailPage.Master>
  <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
      <x:Arguments>
        <local:UnpaidVehicle />
      </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
  </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

When I am trying to do `CityClick.Clicked += asyn .... await Navigation...(new Cities());` in MainPage. It throw error: `System.InvalidOperationException: PushAsync is not supported globally on Android, please use a NavigationPage.` , because I am doing it in MasterDetailPage and that action only possible when MainPage inherits ContentPage class. How I can work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PushModalAsync` creates a popup type of page over your current page. Whereas `PushAsync` replaces the current page.

You can go through the link below :
https://jfarrell.net/2015/01/22/understanding-xamarin-forms-navigation/

Update from the comments below the solution was :

```
await this.Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new Cities());
```

Comment: do you have any idea how I can work around this? Because I don't need popup page, I need to replace existing page and to have navigation bar with back to previous page function.

Comment: set MainPage=new NavigationPage(yourpage); And then for the other pages you use `pushasync`

Comment: It throw error: System.Exception: Android only allows one navigation page on screen at a time . When I am debugning this App.cs line: MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage()); it shows, that MainPage is null.

Comment: In debugging you will not get any page as intellisense is not supported. But what is you MainPage? You cannot set the same page as navigation page. You must use another page.

Comment: My MainPage inherits of : MasterDetailPage . There are burger and other button which navigates to another page. But I need to set MainPage. I think main problem is because MainPage ingerits from MasterDetailPage

Comment: The flow goes this way. Set your MasterDetailPage as your mainpage. After that for each link you click you use `pushasync`.

Comment: My main page is already set up: public partial class MainPage : MasterDetailPage . Or I have to to differently?

Comment: Im talking about Application.Current.MainPage which you set the first time from App.cs

Comment: So from App.cs you set `Application.Current.MainPage=new MainPage();` and After this for all your links set `Navigation.PushAsync(new OtherPage());`.

Comment: And I got same error: System.InvalidOperationException: PushAsync is not supported globally on Android, please use a NavigationPage.

Comment: My appologies set `Application.Current.MainPage=new NavigationPage(new MainPage());`

Comment: Like I did in previous times, while we have been chatting I got same error: System.Exception: Android only allows one navigation page on screen at a time . When I we did such a line : MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());

Comment: Okay I tried your code. And I came up to a solution `await this.Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new Cities());` This is what you need to use when you are using master detail page. This will add a page on your detail page. I hope this helps.@BinaryTie Provided you put set your detail page as navigation page.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by changing from this: `await Navigation.PushAsync(new (new Cities());` to this : `await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Cities());` . So I still don't understand differences between `PushAsync` versus `PushModalAsync` . Also after that implemetation my cities page appear, but navigation bar disappears. Does any one know why my navigation bar disappear?