# Xamarin portable, how to navigate back from selected list item to MainPage and pass value

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, cross-platform, xamarin.forms

My previous question was, how to navigate from ToolbarItem to another page and keep navigation bar existing. : [Xamarin portable project navigate with ToolbarItem to another page by using MasterDetailPage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37255097/xamarin-portable-project-navigate-with-toolbaritem-to-another-page-by-using-mast)
Now I have troubles when I select item from item list and I want to back to my MainPage, but I am getting such a error: `System.Exception: Android only allows one navigation page on screen at a time` and MainPage page appear, but it freeze and I see now 2 buttons on navigation bar. But it should be only one.Here in MainPage I am calling Cities:

```
public partial class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
    { public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            masterPage.ListView.ItemSelected += OnItemSelected;
            CityClick.Clicked += async (sender, e) =>
            {
                await Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new Cities());
            };}}
```

Then when I am at Cities.xaml.cs I want to back to MainPage(). And also I want pass my selected item value from list to my label in MainPage.xaml navigation. Second  problem is when I am returning from Cities.xaml.cs after item select to MainPage() I am getting that error which I mentioned before. This is my Cities class:

```
public partial class Cities : ContentPage
    {
        public Cities()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Label header = new Label
            {
                Text = ...
            };
            List<City> cities = new List<City>
            {new City("City1"),
             new City("City2")};

            ListView listView = new ListView
            {ItemsSource = cities,
                ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
                {
                    Label nameLabel = new Label();
                    nameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Name");
                    BoxView boxView = new BoxView();
                    return new ViewCell
                    {
                        ...
                    };
            ...
            {
                Children =
                {
                    ...
                }
            };
            listView.ItemSelected += async (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (e.SelectedItem == null)
                {return;}
                else
                {
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
                }
            };
        }
        class City
        {public City(string name)
            {
                this.Name = name;
            }
            public string Name { private set; get; }
        };}
```

And this is how looks when returns to MainPage() it freeze everything and appear another label:

[image]

**EDIT :** Regarding @AkashAmin comments I changed from `await Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());` to `await Navigation.PopAsync();` and it is worked very well. Now I still have dilemma with pasiing value from City class to MainPage class.

Comment: Why don't you pop your current page from the navigation stack as the Detail Page in MainPage is already in the stack.

Comment: @AkashAmin That's why I don't want to pop my page. I just want that it would be linear. I go to Cities, then select item and return back to my MainPage, but not pop up another page in stack. Just back after item selection.

Comment: Yes POP means you are removing the current page Cities from the stack. So you will get the main page back.

Comment: Actually `PopAsync();` worked well in Cities class. Now I just need to pass selected item to MainPage somehow and I want to see selected city in cities: label

Comment: You can use System.Current.Properties or you can create a static field.

Comment: Where I can define System.Current.Properties ? And how to pass from one class to another class this value?

Comment: Sorry its Application.Current.Properties. Use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32269002/xamarin-forms-sharedpreferences-cross

Comment: Application.Current.Properties can be accessed form anywhere. It is like session.

Comment: I don't have any string to input after Application.Current.Properties [''] . Is there are any more alternatives?

Comment: Create a public Static Class with your fields as get; set; and then you can access them from anywhere. Application.Current.Properties[""] can also store objects though.

Comment: Is it valid class in Cities class: City? There I defined field Name get; set; . Then I am trying to access from MainPage to that property , but unfortunately unsuccessfully :(

Comment: I will need to see your code for that. From the mainpage you convert the the property to your object as `var yourobject=(yourclassname)Application.Current.Properties["yourkey"]`.

Comment: I pasted my Cities class in this question. And you can see bellow my City class with Name property.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112292/discussion-between-akash-amin-and-binarytie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I navigated back from my Cities class to my MainPage by changing from `PushAsync` to `PopAsync();` . Thank you @Akash Amin for your information. This awaited task also solved duplicated labels problem in Navigation ToolbarItems place .

Also I solved value passing from Cities to MainPage class problem. In this link you can see my all walkthrough of solving this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37350738/3727758