# Xamarin passing list item value, from one class to MainPage class ToolbarItem

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Many hours I am trying to pass ItemSelected value to my MainPage ToolbarItem `x:name="CityClick"`. This is my code of Cities class and City class behind of Cities class:

```
public partial class Cities : ContentPage
    {
        private Action<object, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs> onItemSelected;
        public Cities()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Label header = new Label
            {
                Text = "Select here",
                FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label)),
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
            };
            List<City> cities = new List<City>
            {
                new City("C1"),
                new City("City2")
            };
            ListView listView = new ListView
            {
                ItemsSource = cities,
                ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
                {
                    Label nameLabel = new Label();
                    nameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Name");
                    BoxView boxView = new BoxView();
                    return new ViewCell
                    {
                        View = new StackLayout
                        {
                            Padding = new Thickness(0, 5),
                            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                            Children =
                            {
                                ...
                            }
                        }
                    };
                })
            };
            this.Padding = new Thickness(10, Device.OnPlatform(20, 0, 0), 10, 5);
            this.Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Children =
                {
                    ..
                }
            };
            listView.ItemSelected += async (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (e.SelectedItem == null)
                {
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    await Navigation.PopAsync();
                }

            };
        }
        public Cities(Action<object, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs> onItemSelected)
        {
            this.onItemSelected = onItemSelected;
        }
    }
    public class City
    {
        public City()
        {
            this.Name = Name;
        }
        public City(string name)
        {
            this.Name = name;
        }
        public string Name { set; get; }
    };
```

This is my MainPage class where I initialize City() class, but when I am debugging it shows null for obj.Name :

```
public partial class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            masterPage.ListView.ItemSelected += OnItemSelected;

            CityClick.Clicked += async (sender, e) =>
            {
                await Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new Cities());
            };
            City obj = new City();
            Cities obj2 = new Cities();
            var myobject = Application.Current.Properties[CityClick.Text];
            myobject = obj.Name;
            if (obj.Name == null)
            {
                if (Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey(CityClick.Text))
                {
                    var id = Application.Current.Properties[CityClick.Text] as string;
                    CityClick.Text = obj.Name;
                }
            }
        }}
```

And this is MainPage xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LearningProject;assembly=LearningProject"
                  x:Class="LearningProject.MainPage"
          MasterBehavior="Popover">
  <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem x:Name="CityClick"
                 Text="City:"
                 Order="Primary">
    </ToolbarItem>
  </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
  <MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <local:MasterPage x:Name="masterPage" />
  </MasterDetailPage.Master>
  <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
      <x:Arguments>
        <local:UnpaidVehicle />
      </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
  </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

So when I am debuging, it is shows that ItemSelected hold some string name. But when I am debuging MainPage.xaml.cs it shows that it is null. Why obj.Name do not reach value from Cities class?

Comment: I see several issues in your question:
While you are subscribing to an event on the `MasterPage` class, I don't see a definition of that page in your sample code.
Your event handler for the `ListView` in the CitiesPage only pops the navigation stack; it doesn't bubble anything up or set a property that can be accessed from a containing element.

Comment: @AndyHopper Hi, you mean that subscribe CityClick.Clicked += ? Why I have to define something here? It is just a simple navigation to antoher page. yes that listView in Cities page not really related to anything, I will fix it.

Comment: @AndyHopper actually that event handler is needy , I tried to execute it without, and I got bunch of errors.

Comment: No, CityClick is just a toolbar item. I'm referring to the fact that your `Cities` ContentPage doesn't do anything with the `ListItem` selection to publish it to an outside observer/consumer. I see an overload for the `Cities` page that takes an `Action`; I'm presuming you intended to have that be a publication mechanism. I would recommend that you do not do that. Instead, define a public property on `Cities` that exposes the currently selected `City`, publish a "selection changed" event, set the property and fire the change event.

Comment: I would also recommend not popping the navigation stack in `Cities`; let the subscriber to the change event handle that to separate that concern from `Cities`.

Comment: I don't Have `ListItem` in Cities class. For `Action` I already deleted one method. How to define public property that exposes current selected `City` and to publish as "Selection changed" event?

Comment: @AndyHopper What could be in Cities instead of navigation stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok , so I solved value passing issue in such a way: I changed `private Action<object, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs> onItemSelected;` to `public event EventHandler<SelectedItemChangedEventArgs> OnSelectedCity;` This event handler will be used in MainPage class. And It will detects when item is selected. Then in listView.ItemSelected else section I added parsing of my selected object : `OnSelectedCity((City)e.SelectedItem, null);` Full else section looks like this:

```
                else
                {
                    ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
                    if (OnSelectedCity != null)
                    {
                        OnSelectedCity((City)e.SelectedItem, null);
                    }
                    await Navigation.PopAsync();
                }
```

Then in MainPage class of CityClick.Clicked event I initialize `Cities` class like this:

```
CityClick.Clicked += async (sender, e) =>
            {
                Cities page = new Cities();
                page.OnSelectedCity += Page_OnSelectedCity;
                await Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(page);
            };
```

Here I call event from Cities class. And I create automaticly `Page_OnSelectedCity` method. There I pass object value of class and assign it to my CityClick.Text label of ToolBarItem, there I see value from my `City` class!

```
void Page_OnSelectedCity(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var city = (City)(sender);
            CityClick.Text = city.Name;
        }
```